# Hiding The TopBar

Tags: objective-c

I have tried 3 ways of hiding the top navigation bar but its not hiding.

1. in viewDidAppear I have tried

   ```
   [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
   ```
2. Conformed to UINavigationControllerDelegate with this code,

   ```
   (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                 willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)
                           viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
   {



   BOOL shouldHide = [viewController.toolbarItems count] == 0;
   [navigationController setToolbarHidden:shouldHide animated:animated];


   }
   ```

TopbarHidden is also set to True in the inspector and when Im loading the the nib into the UIView like this...

```
UINavigationController *NAV_instructions = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:instructions];

[NAV_instructions setToolbarHidden:YES];
[NAV_instructions setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
```

How do I hide to top bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```